# parse XmlPullParser object

Tags: java

I have an XmlPullParse object and i want to parse it into string but the thing is that i want to keep the original tags in the string.
for example if the xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This is a comment -->
<address>
  <name>Lars </name>
  <street> Test </street>
  <telephone number= "0123"/>
</address>
```

I want the parsed string will look like that:

```
String stringXml = "<?xml version="1.0"?> " +
    "<!-- This is a comment -->" + 
    "<address>" + 
      "<name>Lars </name>" + 
      "<street> Test </street>" + 
      "<telephone number= "0123"/>" + 
    "</address> ";
```

Is it possible to do that? and if so how?
Thanks in advanced.

Best.

Comment: You can use `.getText()` and `.getName()`.

Comment: and then build the string by my self?
I'm looking for a one line of code (if one exist) to do that.